# Get part of a string after n spaces

Tags: php, string, substr

if I have a string for example like this :

```
$text = '12 24 40 59 101 302 340 ';
```

How do I always get the last number (in this case 340), care there is also a space at the end, which I dont want :x, also the last number can be a 1 digit number or even a 10 digit number so just getting the last 4 chars of the string and then removing the space won't work :)
ty in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$text = trim('12 24 40 59 101 302 340 ');
$value = end(explode(" ", $text));
```

Explanation:

trim() removes the space at the end of your string. explode() converts the string to an array divided by space and end() takes the last value of that array

Comment: damn thats genius ty :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
$text = '12 24 40 59 101 302 340 ';

$numbers = explode(' ', trim($text));
$lastNumber = end($numbers);
```